# Can this find command be made more compact?

Tags: find

Please look at these two commands:

`find ~/{Documents,Desktop,Downloads,Music,Videos} -mmin -120 -type f`
and
`find . ! -path "*opera*" ! -path "*mozilla*" ! -path "*google-chrome*" -mmin -120 -type f`

While the first tells `find` to give results relating to specific folders, the second does the opposite. But is there a way to make the second command more compact or does `! path` have to precede each folder?

The OS is Lubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU `find` regular expressions (non standard extension):

```
find . -regextype posix-extended ! -regex '.*(opera|mozilla|google-chrome).*'
```

You can maybe use a different (more efficient) `-regextype`, I didn't check.

*Chris Down*'s solution is not exactly the same thing as your second `find` command because it does *not* exclude your pattern from subdirectories (it would still find something like `./somedir/some-mozilla-dir`).

The above command does not have this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the limitation in my command, I missed it.

Comment: @ChrisDown You're welcome :) However, using `zsh`, something like `setopt extendedglob` and then `**/*~*opera*~*mozilla*~*google-chrome*` should match what you want to (`~` means exclude).